# android change background image from settings

Tags: android, android-activity, background, settings, drawable

In my application, four activies are present (Add, view , search and settings). in settings activity, it will display 10 buttons ie. apply to set background image. images are saved in drawable folder. if i click on button image it should change the background of all activities

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

set value of selected background in `SharedPreference` and display images according to the value of it in all `Activities`

Comment: thanks ... can u plz provide sample link im new to android

Comment: check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)